# AS3: having problems implementing correct rotation with atan2

Tags: actionscript-3, math

I have the following scenario: player is in the middle of the screen and never moves from those coordinates. If I click with the mouse on the far right of the screen, the A* script kicks in and moves the background the player is on according with its own walkable/not walkable criteria, so for example if there is an obstacle in between the center of the screen where the player always is in the far right of the screen, the background correctly moves in the opposite direction  And when needed moves around the obstacle, so you have the illusion of player walking, but instead only the background moves.

my problem is that I don't know how to rotate my player to simulate that he is following the path that the actual background is making. For example, in the beginning, the player is facing down. If I click on the right side of the screen, the player should face right. When an obstacle is present, the player should face the direction of the path around the obstacle and so on

but again technically my player never moves, so I don't know what coordinates should I have the  atan2 use. In my mind I thought that the player should rotate toward  the center of the next  best hop in the array of best path created during the A* script, but for some reason I can't figure out the correct coordinates y and x for the atan2 command

I bet this is a simple thing I overlooked, but apparently my mind is in shutdown mode, so I can use a new fresh perspective :-)

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do not code in brain shutdown mode, this can save you lots of brainhurt time.

You don't need `atan2()` in this scenario, since your player is technically on a grid instead of on the screen. Give the player internal coordinates on the grid that will be updated as the player walks around the world, and use them in your A* script. The A* script generates a sequence of tiles the player should walk, thus you derive player's facing from current and next tile, for example, if the next tile to walk is adjacent upwards, you make the player face up and continue moving.

Comment: ah, it makes sense! :-) so I had the right idea, but with the wrong approach. Thank you very much for this, I'll go take a break now, hopefully a brain well rested will be more effective :-)